# How to load my 3d object not come from public folder?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I would like to know if there's a way that I can load my 3d object (.glb) that will be uploaded to my AWS server then I will going to get the endpoint. I tried but there was an error saying "THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost"

The file path of this is the public folder

```
 <Suspense fallback={<div  style={{color: 'white' }} className="center">loading</div>}>
      <div style={{height: '100vh' }}>
      <Canvas style={{background: '#000000' }} pixelRatio={[1, 2]} camera={{ position: [-2, 2, 2], fov: 40,}}>
      <directionalLight position={[-5, 10, 5]} intensity={1.5} />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.7} />
        <spotLight intensity={0.5} angle={0.1} penumbra={1} position={[10, 15, 10]} castShadow />
        <Model url="/character.glb" position-y={0.2} scale={[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]} />
        <OrbitControls />
      </Canvas>
      </div>
    </Suspense>
```